# which port number to choose for docker container

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm new to docker and when I make a container with port number 8501 it works fine, but I need to have multiple containers and when I use a new port number like 8502 it doesn't work. here is how I make and use the container which was explaied [here](https://neptune.ai/blog/how-to-serve-machine-learning-models-with-tensorflow-serving-and-docker). I call the function make_prediction. this works correcty:

```
docker run -p 8501:8501 --name tfserving_classifier --mount type=bind,source=C:/Users/untitled6/voice_classifier/,target=/models/voice_classifier -e MODEL_NAME=voice_classifier -t tensorflow/serving
```

```
def make_prediction(instances,url):
   data = json.dumps({"signature_name": "serving_default", "instances": instances.tolist()})
   headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
   json_response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
   predictions = json.loads(json_response.text)['predictions']
   return predictions

url = 'http://localhost:8501/v1/models/voice_classifier:predict'
predictions = make_prediction(x_test,url)
```

But when I change the port number to make a new container an error is shown:

```
docker run -p 8502:8502 --name tfserving_classifier1 --mount type=bind,source=C:/Users/untitled6/voice_classifier1/,target=/models/voice_classifier1 -e MODEL_NAME=voice_classifier1 -t tensorflow/serving
```

```
def make_prediction(instances,url):
   data = json.dumps({"signature_name": "serving_default", "instances": instances.tolist()})
   headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
   json_response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
   predictions = json.loads(json_response.text)['predictions']
   return predictions

url = 'http://localhost:8502/v1/models/voice_classifier1:predict'
predictions = make_prediction(x_test,url)
```

The error:
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

So how can I have multiple containers? I need them because I need to use about 10 different models in my application.

Comment: Is anything else already using 8502?

Comment: Does 8503 or 8504 work?

Comment: @Sayse I tried some other port numbers but they didn't work, and how can I know if a port is being used? Sorry i'm a beginner

Comment: @BlackFox  I just checked them and they had error.

Comment: Run the curl command from the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/language/nodejs/run-containers/.......this will test your url...you tested the port numbers...now test the url using another method...like a curl command.

Comment: Next check if your container is even running... docker ps

Comment: Finally...does your python application have a main.py or app.py file that defines ports? Did you define ports as 8501...and not change it for the 8502 instance of your app? Did you define your port in the main.py or app.py file as 0.0.0.0? See here for how to test and config for python https://docs.docker.com/language/python/run-containers/....note they recommend in the example to use 5000...maybe config your python app to us that port to test with documentation?....lastly take a look in the docs at the structure of the python app in the example...try to match the logic.

Answer (score 1):

The second `-p` port number always needs to match the port number the program inside the container is listening on.  The two port numbers don't need to match.

If the main container process always listens on port 8501, then you can remap it by using a different port number for the first port number, and keeping the second port number the same:

```sh
#                  vvvv fixed, matches what the application runs
docker run -p 8502:8501 ...
#             ^^^^ your choice of externally-accessible port
```

(One more common variant of this is around MySQL: the standard MySQL port is 3306, so if you want a different host port for your database, you need an option like `-p 3307:3306`; if the second port number isn't the standard port number the database will be unreachable in this same way.)